# Why is the $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} x\cos(\frac{1}{x})=0$?

Tags: calculus

Can anyone explain why the $$\lim\limits_{x \to 0} x\cos(\frac{1}{x})=0$$

Comment: Use the definition of a limes and that $\cos$ is bounded (always between $-1$ and $1$).

Comment: Think about the inside and the outside. cos is always bounded and the outside obviously goes to 0.

Comment: Just "plug in" 0 for x because both functions (and their product) are defined at x = 0. I think its only when they are not that you cannot just "plug in" the number...

Comment: @zerosofthezeta perhaps you missed the $1/x$ inside the cosine, because $\cos(1/x)$ is not defined at $x=0$.

Comment: @AntonioVargas Yes, I did miss it...I thought it was just cos(x) - thx!

Answer (score 6):

$|x \cos(\frac{1}{x})| \le |x|$.